# Returning String from if statement in forEach loop is undefined

Tags: javascript, foreach

in this code, I used a forEach loop inside the function to iterate over the arrays at the bottom. Basically, if the array contains the string June, I should return "Summer Break! else return, "Have a great day." My only restriction for this exercise, is to not use a variable to store the result I am returning.

I think my issue lies somewhere in the return sections of the if/else statements. From the console I get undefined. Is it because a forEach loop returns undefined? What would you use as a suggestion? Filter? A for loop? While loop?

Any tools in the future I can use to diagnose this?

```js
function holidayDays(arr) {

  arr.forEach(function(items) {
    if (items === "June") {
      return "Summer Break!";
    } else {
      if (items !== "June")
        return "Have a great day!";
    }

  });

}


// Uncomment these to check your work!
const months = ["April", "May", "June", "October"];
const animals = ["Cats", "Dogs", "Pigs"];
console.log(holidayDays(months)); // should return: "Happy Halloween"
console.log(holidayDays(animals)); // should return: "Have a great day!"
```

Comment: You're returning to the forEach callback function and not your `holidayDays` function. Use a regular for loop such as `for...of` instead (also make sure that you don't accidentally terminate your loop/function early by returning)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if an element is present in the array.

```js
const holidayDays = (arr) => {
  return arr.includes('June') ? 'Summer Break!' : 'Have a great day!'
}

const months = ['April', 'May', 'June', 'October']
const animals = ['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Pigs']

console.log(holidayDays(months))
console.log(holidayDays(animals))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
const holidayDays = (arr) =>
  arr.some((item) => item === "June") ? "Summer Break!" : "Have a great day!";

const months = ["April", "May", "June", "October"],
  animals = ["Cats", "Dogs", "Pigs"];
console.log(holidayDays(months));
console.log(holidayDays(animals));
```

Comment: The condition should be `item === 'June'` and not `item.includes('June')` since `item` is a string.